Is there a HNSW graph stats API in Elasticsearch?
I am testing the recall accuracy of ANN algorithm in Elasticsearch (using the knn query operator) for my dataset by changing the num_candidates parameter. Based on my understanding of the HNSW algorithm, the num_candidates is the number of entry points Lucene considers at the top most layer in the NSW hierarchy. So if the num_candidates is set to 10_000 (say) I want to make sure there are at least 10_000 graph nodes in the top most layer. Is there an Elasticsearch API that returns stats (like number of nodes in each hierarchy and number of hierarchies (or layers)) about the HNSW graph structure that gets built on each shard in a cluster?

There isn't, but you might find this and this useful.
